# Extending WP_Query — Optimise SQL query

Tags: wp-query, sql, posts-where

I'm storing posts, a user follows in a custom table that has the columns `id`, `post_id` and `user_id`. To fetch posts that a user follows I have extended the WP_Query as follows:

```
class WP_Query_Posts_User_Follows extends WP_Query {
    function __construct($args=array()) {
        if ( !empty($args['followed_by']) ) {
            $this->followed_by = $args['followed_by'];
            add_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'posts_where'));
        }
        parent::query($args);
    }

    function posts_where($where) {
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'post_followed_by';
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM $table WHERE user_id = %d)", $this->followed_by);
        return $where;
    }
}
```

If you notice there is sub-query in the `WHERE` clause. My understanding is that sub-queries are bad as they hinder performance and particularly in this case where the sub-query could potentially return hundred or thousands of `post_ids` that a user follows. What are the alternatives that I have, considering that I need to work with WP_Query and cannot run a custom SQL directly using `wpdb`?

Comment: I think you have no alternatives. You can perform the subquery and pass the result array inside the 'IN' clause, but is this better? I really don't think so. Maybe you can perform the query via ajax and give a visual feedback standing by results...

Comment: +1 for a perfect question. Sadly I don't think optimizing SQL queries (even if in the context of WP) fits this site. Leaving no close vote as I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Benchmark it. Do not worry about performance issue until you profile and study it.

Comment: A `JOIN` _may_ perform better than the where clause but what you have is a pretty straightforward query. With the right indexes there may be no problem. But I agree with @kaiser. This is a pure SQL question and probably best asked wlsewhere, perhaps here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rarst Benchmarking would not be possible immediately as I have no real data to play with. This is still in design stage, so I have the possibility of redesigning it if you have some alternate suggestions in terms of storing and retrieving data.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I'm not sure if joins can be performed using filters as above. Is that possible?

Comment: @John : [There is a `posts_join` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters).

Comment: @s_ha_dum `posts_join` filter! Awesome. I guess now I need to get an opinion on dba.stackexchange.com and see what would work better. I'd agree with you that a join may perform better.

Comment: @John then you are asking for hypothetical solution, to hypothetical problem on database schema that isn't native to WordPress. I concur this calls for different stack. :)

Comment: @Rarst I absolutely agree with you. But this dilemma is part and parcel of the design stage. I would not want to build something that falls apart when loaded. So an opinion from others would help me take an informed decision.

Comment: @John No need to over consider this in design stage. You're handling the same data anyway. Just use the `posts_clauses`, or the `posts_where` and `posts_join` filters later on when you got some real data. Then please revisit this post and show us your benchmarks or work with the people on possible ways to go on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, however it will require the ability to make custom SQL queries - with $wpdb.

Since you want to get posts followed by a user, you can create a view, with the following structure:

```
id user_id post_id post_title post_content ... (all other post fields)
```

don't worry about duplicating posts.

When you select, you just have to do a simple `select * from the_view where...` .

Later you can cache results from this view using memcache or other object cache technique to make it faster.

Answer (score -2):

You use the best way:)
Maybe, if you want to optimize your query you can use posts 2 posts plugin. You will not need to filter the query.
Link - https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something happens to that link the answer becomes useless. Please try to make your answer here stand alone. And see [answer].